# html append square div in 4 directions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

First, you will see square number 1 , 
when you press the + on top of square 1 , 
square 2 will come out and you can press the + on right of square 2,
then square 3 will come out.

can i do this? or how can i do this?

[image: Example]

Comment: will come out from where?

Comment: Please show your efforts show your code.

Comment: Sure you can. Is there a specific problem we can help you with in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, the [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) methods are what you're after, along the lines of:

```
$('#one').click(function() {
  $('#two').show();
});
$('#two').click(function() {
  $('#three').show();
});
```

If you want animation read up on jQuery's [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

Hopefully this helps you get started:

https://jsfiddle.net/qb7mr9b6/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example of what you want, hope you find your solution.

```
$('.show1').click(function() {
  $('#two').show();
});
$('.show2').click(function() {
  $('#three').show();
});
```

here is the link for complete working example 
https://jsfiddle.net/ahmerrkhanzz/7tso9rvs/

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can do it, You will find my solution in Jsfiddle in this below

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
   jQuery('.plus').on('click', function() {
    if(jQuery('.one').is(":visible") != true){
     jQuery('.one').removeClass('hide');
    }else {
     jQuery('.two').removeClass('hide');
    }
 }); 
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: grey;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.hide {
  display: none !important;
}

.plus {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <div class="box one hide">2</div>
        </td>
        <td><a href="javascript:;" class="plus one hide">+</a></td>
        <td>
          <div class="box two hide">3</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><a href="javascript:;" class="plus">+</a>
          <div class="box">1</div>
        </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```